# How can I make the background inactive when I show a popup in Windows phone 8.1..?

Tags: popup, windows-phone-8.1, popupwindow

I have created a popup in Windows phone 8.1. But the user can click buttons in the background. Can I disable this feature of popup...ie. I want the background to be unresponsive when popup is shown.

```
How to achieve this....?
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add another layer that will cover the whole layout below the popup.

Example:

```xml
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="can't touch this"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.4" />
        <Popup />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I used `Grid` to achieve this. You can even set the opacity to 0, so the layer will be completely invisible, but will still block user input. But it's important that `Background` property is not `Transparent`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

Have all your layout in one panel, and the popup in another.

Then, when the popup is shown, just set the IsHitTestVisible of the panel in which the rest of the layout is to False.

```
<Grid Name="EverythingOnPage" ..... >
    // layout
</Grid>
```

When popup is shown:

```
EverythingOnPage.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```